# sudo su - user works but 'sudo -H -S -n -u user/bin/sh -c''echo test" doesn't work

Tags: linux

I need to run the command using playbook.xml i.e. sudo -H -S -n -u user/bin/sh -c''echo test" on a remote server using a user
However, getting the below error

> fatal: [staging]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "command"}, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

I have edited the sudoers file on remote server

> user=user ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

If I execute the command sudo su - user it works, but not the udo -H -S -n -u user/bin/sh -c''echo test"

Any idea for the same.

Aman

Comment: I am just curious but is there a space between "user /bin/sh" or not? .... sudo -H -S -n -u user /bin/sh -c''echo test"

Comment: yes there is a space

Comment: did you tried it without the "-S" parameter? ... sudo -H -n -u user /bin/sh -c''echo test"

Comment: yes, it didn't work

Comment: script is executed using user A, and in the command user mentioned is user B
sudoers entry is of User A

Comment: I just read more in detail about the sudoers file: "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" should do the trick ... I tested your command and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the right answer:
Please update the sudoers file to

`user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

and it should work.

Regards T2k